# Listen to azure database data changes (CRUD) and on event perform some tasks

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have two databases, main database(let say A) and a subset database(let say B). When there is any change(CRUD) in data on db-A I want that delta change to be manipulated (make a call to a web-service) and then inserted in db-B and vice versa.

Basically I want to listen any CRUD operation and then perform some tasks.

I am using the Microsoft Azure and I would like if there is any azure tool which provides the feature I need.

Both databases are of different schemas.

Comment: I guess you're looking for [Geo-replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview)

Comment: @rickvdbosch No. I want to transfer some of the main database data to the subset not all of it. And the subset is not the replica of main database.

Comment: i am not familiar with azure, but did u tried *Triggers*?

Comment: Triggers would be only inside the sql server. I want to perform some external tasks. e.g send an email.

Comment: Please see this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amitagarwal/2018/01/11/azure-function-apps-trigger-in-azure-sql-sql-server-to-execute-azure-function/. Essentially the idea is to make an HTTP request to an Azure Function inside your SQL Database Trigger and send the relevant data. Once the data reaches Azure Function, you can send emails or send the data to another database etc.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is Azure [SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data). You can select any subset of tables on database A to sync with database B, and you can choose if the sync is bidirectional or not. You will need to define database A as a "hub" database and database B as a "member" database on SQL Data Sync configuration. To get started, please visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync) documentation.

Comment: Thanks Alberto. Just some questions.
- Will I be able to do some additional tasks like sending email etc ?

Comment: I have edited my question please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: If the tables involved between the two databases have different schema you need to consider using triggers instead. Tell me under what circumstances you want to send emails.

Comment: The main database will be used by a web-system and the subset will be used by a mobile application. Whenever the web system do a CRUD on db A I want to manipulate the data and insert it into the db B and when the mobile app do a CRUD on bd B then this data will be manipulated for updating in db A but here I need some other tasks to perform like sending email, etc..

Comment: You can use Azure Send Grid to send email from your application https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/SendGrid.SendGrid?tab=Overview

Comment: Email is just an example there could be many other tasks. Is there any azure tool which I can use to listen for the db changes and perform different tasks.

Comment: Let me know all the features needed. Azure Event Grid and Azure Functions can help trigger events. Azure automation can help you automate tasks.